# Can I play splitscreen on Servers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I'm wondering if two people can play on the same console on Minecraft while playing on a server. For example, if I were to go into a server, then connect another controller, would I be able to play with two controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there’s been a change recently no it’s not possible me and my little brother tried and I cant find anything that says otherwise so as far as I’m concerned no, you can not.

Comment: You can, but you need 2 xbox live accounts

Comment: I have 2 Xbox live acculounts split screen doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't work just like that out of the box, however if you are a little techy and you feel like you can install windows there is a trick, **assuming you are going to do this on PC**. The keyword for this is called **virtual machines**. They are used pretty much everywhere, but most commonly on huge enterprise servers. You can try it out by installing [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org). When setting up a virtual machine make sure it gets sufficient RAM, CPU and video mem.

Now to the controller issue:
they really have to be 2 separate devices. Either wired, or you need 2 separate wireless receivers. It is then possible to map one device to one machine and the other to the other one. By running 2 virtual machines, you can get something like a split screen.

This is the only way I can think of, having multiple minecraft screens with 2 separate controllers on PC.

I really hope this could be somewhat helpful, and have fun tinkering, in case you decide to tackle it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could just run one Minecraft in the VM and then run another Minecraft in the host machine instead of using two VMs

Comment: btw you need a decent computer for this to even be playable, so if you don't have a good PC iut wont work